# Membership not inherited if child added via webform

Tags: civimember, webform-civicrm

Civi 4.6.4 / Drupal 7.38

Goal: Allow a constituent to add family members to their membership.

Issue: When a constituent adds family members, via a civi web form, the relationship is created properly, however the child does not inherit the membership.  However, if as the admin, I go in and edit the relationship, make no changes, and save, the membership is now inherited properly.

In the webform, I am adding the relationship, but not adding any membership...I'm assuming this is not necessary. The parent has an established, active membership at the time of form submission.

Has anybody experienced this or is using another process to achieve this goal?

Thanks,

--Ken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug that requires the acting user to have "access CiviMember" permission or the inherited memberships fail to be processed. I've [submitted a fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6145) for this which hopefully will be part of the next (4.6.5) release.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code, this really should be working. The webform creates the relationship via the api, which calls [CRM_Contact_BAO_Relationship::create](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php#L53), which in turn calls [disableEnableRelationship](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.6/CRM/Contact/BAO/Relationship.php#L696) which handles related memberships. Can you check your drupal error logs for anything from the webform?

Comment: Thanks Coleman for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately nothing in the recent error logs.

Comment: I think I have a permissions issue.  If I add the administrator role to the user, after the membership is created, but before the webform to add a child is submitted, everything works as suspected.  Researching now on what permission is needed, but would be grateful if anybody can point me to it straight away.

Comment: Confirmed permission issue.  CiviMember: access CiviMember was not enabled for this role.

Answer (score 1):

The CiviMember: access CiviMember permission was not enabled for the role in question.  Adding this permission solved the problem.

Comment: This is a good workaround but I think this is still a bug. Inherited memberships working properly should not be dependent on the permissions of whoever happens to be logged in. I'm filing an issue for this...